# rails: pass 2-d array to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a controller `querys` with an action `send_file`.
querys_controller.rb

```
def send_file
    send_data(params[data], :filename => "query.txt")
end
```

in html.erb I have:

```
<%=link_to "send data", :controller=>"querys", :action=>"send_file", :data=>@mat, method: :post%>
```

By clicking on"send data" rails shows me "Bad request" due to the fact that @mat is a 2-D array and it seems I link_to cannot send such structure. How can I send my matrix to my controller ?

```
@mat:  
[["1681", "", "02.05.1955"], ["1680", "", "02.03.1936"], ["1679", "", "26.11.1938"], ["1692", "", "15.05.1958"]]
```

Comment: change `:data=>@mat` to `:data=> { data: @mat}`

Comment: @ArupRakshit did not help

Comment: what's the new error ?

Comment: it is still the same: Bad request

Comment: well what is the class of `@mat` ?

Comment: @mat.class.name says it is an Array

Comment: try `:data=> { report: CSV.new(@mat)}` and `send_data(params[:report], :filename => "query.txt")`

Comment: It works, but how can I access the matrix itself afterwards? send_data throws an error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0). params I am sending are {"data"=>{"report"=>"#<CSV:0x007fa7d4c82728>"}, why do I access it with params[:report] ?

Comment: I am still trying to understand what you are trying to achieve by passing binary data to the browser... see Hugo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Tonja, to me it seems to be very strange what you are doing. First you somewhere generate an array, then pass it over using the browser again back to your application. And then you send it back to the browser in a text format? 
You should not pass this array to the user, but keep it on the server. Just store it in the database. Do not pass data to the user, only when absolutely neccesary. Your current implementation also forces you to do quite some checks on the data that is passed.

In the controller method that generates the html.erb, store the @mat instance somewhere, and get the ID of the record. Pass this ID to the link_to, and use this data from the DB as parameter for the send_data call.

(Small tip: do not actually use the ID, that is not secure, but use a random value. Or even better: do not pass anything at all if you can attach the value to the current_user).

You get the Bad Request because Rails does not understand the format you request. And that is because you assemble the url yourself. Use a call like

```
link_to "send file", send_file_querys_path(format: :txt)
```

or even a

```
button_to ....
```

if it is a POST operation.

You can get the valid routes with 'rake routes'. This makes your app better testable.

I hope my answers help you to rework your code. If what you are doing is the right way, then @m_x gave you the correct pointers.

Best regards,

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

when passing url arguments in the form of a hash, you should separate them from the rest of the arguments for `link_to`:

```
<%
  = link_to "send data", 
            {controller: "querys", action: "send_file", data: @mat}, 
            method: :post
%>
```

However, this will pass the data as query parameters. If you really want to pass the data as POST parameters (for example, if `@mat` contains a lot of data), you will have to use a form tag with a hidden field and a submit button.

IMO a more efficient approach would be to pass the parameters that were required to populate `@mat`, repopulate the variable server-side and use it in `send_file`.

The best practice in this regard is to leverage rails' `format` capabilities, for example :

```
def some_action
  @mat = populate_mat(params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.txt do
      send_data(@mat, :filename => "query.txt")
    end
  end
end
```

*(note : for this to work, you will probably have to register the `txt` mime type in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`)*

then in `some_action.html.erb`:

```
<% = link_to "send data", {format: :txt}, class: 'whatever' %>
```

This will will just add a `.txt` extension at the end of the current url, which plays nicely with the REST paradigm (one endpoint per resource, with the extension indicating the desired representation).

You can also pass the `format` option to any url helper, for example :

```
<%= link_to "root", root_path(format: :txt), class: 'whatever' %>
```

Comment: If I type it as you said, the only params I get are: {"_method"=>"post", "authenticity_token"=>"VlQ2IAU2SuDPLqUtdUcdGkFuSABjSPYLBr4W3GFq3EI=", "action"=>"send_data", "controller"=>"clinicdb_querys", "locale"=>"ru"}, no data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
link_to("Send data", send_file_querys_path(data: @mat), method: :post)
```